# Deploy de aplicação flask no heroku com flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, deploy, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy

Tenho uma pequena aplicação escrita em flask e estou tendo problemas com o banco de dados ao tentar fazer o deploy no heroku e, após pesquisar por dois dias não encontrei nenhuma solução que me atendesse.

Em resumo, esse é o código do meu app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost/jperfil'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.secret_key = '123456789'

#aqui vão os registros de algumas blueprints e imports de classes

db.create_all()
```

Eu posso imaginar que não é assim que se configura um banco para fazer deploy, até porquê essas são as configurações do banco local, mas como configurar de forma que o heroku entenda as configurações e crie meu banco automaticamente?

Comment: Removi o código <code>db.create_all()</code>, porém ainda da erro.

Comment: Não conheço como é o sistema de deploys no heroku mas na GCI (Google Cloud Infrastructure) é utilizado um arquivo de deploy que o que faz é criar o banco de dados, por isso no heroku deves ter que criar o banco de dados manualmente.

Comment: Podes utilizar uma variável de ambiente para evitar ter que editar a database URI antes de fazer deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar o add-on de banco de dados para a sua aplicação heroku (confesso que não entendo muito disso, mas seguindo esse tutorial aqui https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database você vai conseguir desenrolar).

Uma vez configurada esta etapa, a única coisa que você deverá se preocupar na sua aplicação é iniciar corretamente o banco de dados através do comando `create_all` (que você já faz) e setar a variável

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

Desta maneira a sua aplicação irá pegar da variável de ambiente a string de conexão para a base de dados disponibilizada pelo heroku e já iniciada em sua aplicação.